# Java - Skipping element of outer loop if condition is true for any element in inner loop

Tags: java, break, continue

Here's the code:

```java
for ( Element e : elements ){
    boolean shouldContinue = false;
    for ( OtherElement oe : otherElements ){
        if ( e.magicalCondition(oe) ){
            shouldContinue = true;
            break;
        }
    }
    if (shouldContine){
        continue;
    }  
    otherLogic(e);
}
```

What I want done is checking a condition in the inner loop, if said condition is fulfilled, skip this `Element`, but `otherLogic()` should be applied to all other `Elements` where the condition isn't fulfilled.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would split using two or three methods and `Stream`:

```
elements.stream()
        .filter(this::shouldApplyOtherLogic)
        .forEach(this::otherLogic);

boolean shouldApplyOtherLogic(Element e) {
  return otherElements.stream().noneMatch(oe -> e.magicalCondition(oe)); // or e::magicalCondition
}
```

If you are more comfortable with `for`, then a second method would still be better:

```
for (Element e : elements) {
  if (shouldApplyOtherLogic(e)) {
    otherLogic(e);
  }
}

boolean shouldApplyOtherLogic(Element e) {
  for ( OtherElement oe : otherElements) {
    if (e.magicalCondition(oe)) {
      return false;
    }
  }
  return true;
}
```

The quirks is to invert the logic: search element for which you should apply logic then apply logic (rather than finding element for which you don't want to apply logic).

The method also further encompass what your code is doing.

Comment: You can play around with variants of this, too: if you want to unit-test the condition, you can make it package-private and unit test it alone; on the other hand, if you want to cut down on one-use methods, you can inline `shouldApplyOtherLogic` as a lambda to the filter.

Comment: They should put Sonar in StackOverflow, it would've tell me to use e::magicalCondition :)

Answer (score 0):

What you have mentioned is if condition fulfilled, skip `Element`, so I am thinking inner loops else condition needs `break` :

```
for (Element e : elements) {
  for (OtherElement oe : otherElements) {
    if (!e.magicalCondition(oe)) {
      otherLogic(e);
    } else
      break;
  }
}
```